# Angular 2 add highlight to new item in a dynamically generated "list"

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a array of connections that I display using angular 2 and typescript like this:

```
 <div class="list-item" *ngFor="let con of connectors; let i = index" id="con{{i}}" (click)="connectorSelected(con,i)">
                <label class="list-name">{{con.name || "No Available Name"}}</label>
                <label class="list-desc">{{con.description}}</label>
 </div>
```

so basically when I select a connection, it gets highlighted in the typescript function connectorSelected in typescript.

```
private connectorSelected(con: ConnectorModel, index: number) {
        this.removeSelectionOnAllFields();
        let selectedElement = document.getElementById("con" + index);
        selectedElement.className += " selected"
        this.conStatus = SaveStatus.UptoDate;
 }

private removeSelectionOnAllFields() {
    let allClassesHaveSelected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
    while (allClassesHaveSelected.length) {
        allClassesHaveSelected[0].classList.remove("selected");
    }
}
```

However when I created a new connection. I add a new connection to the list and try to highlight that newly created connection, but problem is that the newly created connection has not yet been rendered in the HTML5 webpage yet. This cause the page to throw an error due to the fact that the new connector we added to the array has not been created in the html page yet. Thus no element exist yet, it only creates the element in the webpage after whole function has been executed.

The new connection code :

```
 private newConnector(): void {

    let newConenctor: ConnectorModel = new ConnectorModel();
    this.connectors.push(newConenctor);
    let index: number = this.connectors.length - 1;
    this.removeSelectionOnAllFields();
    let selectedElement = document.getElementById("con" + index);
    selectedElement.className += " selected"
}
```

I would like to know how would should I approach this issue?

Comment: Did you look for the directive [ngClass] ? I think it does exatcly what you want.

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because angular don't trigger the change detection.

In order to solve the probleme, you should copy your array.

```
this.connectors.push(newConenctor);
this.connectors = this.connectors.slice(0);
```

Otherwise like I said in my comment I suggest you to use the directive [ngClass], it much simpler and you don't have to use the global document.

You can find the documentation here:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html